# how to access an object element in a vue js list (nuxt)

Tags: arrays, json, loops, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an array of object like that :

```
{ id: 33617,
  datePublication: 1532266465,
  dateUpdate: 1532266574,
  headline: 'An headline title here',
  images: [ [Object] ] },
{ id: 33614,
  datePublication: 1532265771,
  dateUpdate: 1532271769,
  headline: 'another super headline article',
  images: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
```

so i iterate that way on my vue js template :

```
<v-flex v-for="(ip, i) in ips" :key="i" xs12 sm6 >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-media
        :src="ip.images[0].url"
        height="200px"
      />
      <v-card-title primary-title>
        <div>
          <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{ ip.headline }}</h3>
          <div>Located two hours south of Sydney in the <br>Southern Highlands of New South Wales, ...</div>
        </div>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn flat color="orange">Share</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>  
  </v-flex>
```

And here is my associated script :

```
var api = "https://my api.org/news/fr-FR/2018-25-07";
export default {
data() {
return {};
},
layout: "no-live",
async asyncData({ app }) {
  const ips = await app.$axios.$get(api);
  console.log(ips);
  return { ips };
  }
};
```

Each object in the images array should return me an id and an url, so i want to take that url as a source in my image but i have this error : Cannot read property '0' of undefined

it seems i need to do another loop over the images array, is there a proper way to do that with vue JS ?

Comment: are you looking for the first image only?

Comment: yes i only need the url of the first image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have any objects in `ips` that doesn't have `images`, you would get that error,

you can try to add a conditional to not have an error in rendering

```
  <v-card-media
    v-if="ip.images && ip.images[0]"
    :src="ip.images[0].url"
    height="200px"
  />
```

I usually add a `<pre>{{ip}}</pre>` in these cases to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try put v-if="ip.images" on v-card-media component. You will assure the images are not empty and loaded.